# TCL TK canvas Pixelmap

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I need to generate a pixelmap. I know the height and the width. But now I need to fill one pixel ( or a block for bigger resolution ) on the position x y.
What is the easiest way to do it?

It should not be just one pixel, because its could be to small to view it.
so it would be really good if i could say, my canvas has to height 1024 and with of 768
and the pixelmap just only have 500 x 500 "pixel" so that every point is a little bit bigger.

Could someone help me a little bit ?

Comment: There are lots of examples of manipulating pixmaps with Tcl [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Raster_graphics_operations)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 1x1 filled rectangle on a canvas.

```
% canvas .c
% pack .c
%  .c create rectangle 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 -outline "" -fill black
```

Not really a pixmap, but it is scalable.  Alternately, you could use `bitmap` or `photo` canvas items, which have ways to manipulate them at the pixel level, but can't be scaled as easily.  See http://wiki.tcl.tk/8448 for info and pointers on scaling `photo` canvas items.

Comment: You can scale photo images up, but only by integer factors. See the `zoom` method. Also note, this is an operation on the master; it changes one data point into many.